# How to find IDs of all authors with a given affiliation, including those who were affiliated in the past?

Tags: pybliometrics

I have institution X. For that institution, I need to find the IDs of all authors who have had such an affiliation at any time during their careers. I attempted using this code, where XID is the affiliation_id of the institution X

```
from pybliometrics.scopus import AuthorSearch
query = 'AF-ID(XID)'
s = AuthorSearch(query)
authors = s.authors
authors = pd.DataFrame(authors)
```

When I inspect the list of authors, several scientists, who I know for sure have been affiliated with institution X in the past and have moved to a different place during their career, simply do not appear in the list. It looks as if the query is returning only authors who have a current affiliation with institution X, but not those who had that affiliation in the past.

How could I collect all authors with current and **past** affiliations to institution X?

Thank you.

Comment: If you accept the answer, it will mark the question as solved (provided the answer was helpful, of course)

Answer (score 0):

For XID = 60105007 (my institute), I find both current and former colleagues.

One can see this from the fact that `s.authors` includes information on the current affiliation ID, which might differ:

```
import pandas as pd
from pybliometrics.scopus import AuthorSearch

XID = "60105007"
query = f'AF-ID({XID})'
s = AuthorSearch(query)

authors = pd.DataFrame(s.authors)

different_aff = authors["affiliation_id"] != XID
different_aff.sum()
```

14 out of 96 researchers somehow affiliated with institution 60105007 published at least their paper while affiliated with another one.

Very likely that those authors that you'd expect to be part of your institution are not properly assigned to this very institution profile. Oftentimes there are duplicate affiliation profiles, assigned to some non-org affiliation profile. That's due to difficulties relating from string parsing. Buth each of them is small in terms of associated authors.